# per-link (VPN) systemd-resolved configuration but keep link unmanaged by systemd-networkd

Tags: systemd, openvpn, vpn, systemd-networkd, systemd-resolved

#### Background

I manage my WLAN interface through *systemd-networkd* and use *systemd-resolved* for the whole system.
I have several VPN connections managed by OpenVPN or Openconnect. I have them properly configured to set the DNS information via the *systemd-resolved* API (done e.g. by `/etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved`) and it works.

#### The issue

Unfortunately, by default the VPN links have `DNSDefaultRoute=yes` as reported by `resolvectl`. This means that when the VPN connection is interrupted, DNS resolution on the system can hang sometimes.

#### The goal

I'd like to set `DNSDefaultRoute=no` for these VPN interfaces, but keep them **un**managed by *systemd-networkd*, i.e. let the VPN tools configure the interfaces.

More generally, my question is whether it is possible to have a per-link *systemd-resolved* configuration **without** having the links managed by *systemd-networkd*.

#### What I tried thus far

I attempted to create a file `/etc/systemd/network/30-tun-no-default-route.network` with the contents

```
[Match]
Name=tun_*

[Link]
Unmanaged=true

[Network]
DNSDefaultRoute=false
```

I tested that with `Unmanaged=false` the links get the proper `DNSDefaultRoute=false` setting, but of course by then *systemd-networkd* breaks the VPN connection. Unfortunately, with `Unmanaged=true`, resolved seems to ignore this setting.

To me this seems like *systemd-resolved* does not interpret `*.network` files itself. However, this makes it hard to set such resolved-related settings per-link. Perhaps I should submit a feature request for this?

Another possible workaround is to have the VPN post-scripts run `resolvectl default-route $IFACE`, but that to me seems unsystematic and to go against the purpose of having a declarative-style configuration as done with most *systemd* stuff.